# How do I get SQL server 2008r2 to show me the Errors?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I am running an Insert script that is supposed to insert 13,381 rows into a blank DB from SSMS. Its telling my "Query completed with errors" and is only inserting 13357 rows.

Nothing is showing up in the Error list. How do I locate the mistakes in the script?

Thank you!

Comment: I just had a similar issue and apparently it was because of a too big batch. I've split my batch into 4 peices with GO statements and not it works fine without failing.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

try this:

```
begin try

    --your inserts here

end try
begin catch
    --returns the complete original error message as a result set
    SELECT 
        ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber
        ,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity
        ,ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState
        ,ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure
        ,ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine
        ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage

    --will return the complete original error message as an error message
    DECLARE @ErrorMessage nvarchar(400), @ErrorNumber int, @ErrorSeverity int, @ErrorState int, @ErrorLine int
    SELECT @ErrorMessage = N'Error %d, Line %d, Message: '+ERROR_MESSAGE(),@ErrorNumber = ERROR_NUMBER(),@ErrorSeverity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),@ErrorState = ERROR_STATE(),@ErrorLine = ERROR_LINE()
    RAISERROR (@ErrorMessage, @ErrorSeverity, @ErrorState, @ErrorNumber,@ErrorLine)
end catch
```

Comment: If you add "WITH LOG" at the end of RAISERROR it will place a copy of the error in the SQL Server application log. Note these rules "Logs the error in the error log and the application log for the instance of the Microsoft SQL Server Database Engine. Errors logged in the error log are currently limited to a maximum of 440 bytes. Only a member of the sysadmin fixed server role or a user with ALTER TRACE permissions can specify WITH LOG."

Comment: I was having this error message with no information when 15 sql text editor panel was open ,I closed all sql text editor panels and opened script to run and worked..

Comment: this executed the script but after 55 minutes this error :`A transport-level error has occurred when sending the request to the server. (provider: TCP Provider, error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.)`

Comment: @stom that is a internet connectivity issue.